# How can I center the virtual keyboard on bottom before it is shown - javafx

Tags: javafx, virtual-keyboard

How can I center the keyboard on the bottom of the screen? 
I just have the sizes of the keyboard/PopupWindow after the board is already shown. Before calling show() every function returns 0.0 for the asked width. I could set the position correctly if I just knew the width before.
The keyboard size might change later, that's why I can't do it with a set size.
I am using the [fx-onscreen-keyboard](https://github.com/comtel2000/fx-experience)

My little service:

```
public class KeyboardService {

private double screenWidth = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getWidth();
private double screenHight = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getHeight();
private double keyboardPosX = 0.0;
private double keyboardPosY = 0.0; 

private KeyBoardPopup keyboardPopup;

public KeyboardService() {
    keyboardPopup = KeyBoardPopupBuilder.create().initLocale(Locale.GERMAN).build();
    keyboardPopup.setAutoHide(true);
    keyboardPopup.setConsumeAutoHidingEvents(false);
    keyboardPopup.getKeyBoard().setScale(2.5);
    keyboardPopup.getKeyBoard().setLayer(DefaultLayer.DEFAULT);

    keyboardPopup.getKeyBoard().setOnKeyboardCloseButton((e) -> {
        keyboardPopup.hide();
    });

}

public void showKeyboard(Node node){
    keyboardPosX = (screenWidth - keyboardPopup.getWidth())/2;
    //keyboardPosX = (screenWidth - keyboardPopup.getKeyBoard().getWidth())/2;
    keyboardPosY = screenHight;
    keyboardPopup.show(node, keyboardPosX, keyboardPosY);
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width of the keyboard is defined when the popup that holds it is laid out, what happens right after you call `show`.

The easy way to do this is by listening to the `widthProperty` of the `KeyBoardPopup`, to get the new value, and then moving the window of the popup accordingly.

This will do:

```
public KeyboardService() {
    keyboardPopup = KeyBoardPopupBuilder.create().initLocale(Locale.GERMAN).build();
    keyboardPopup.setAutoHide(true);
    keyboardPopup.setConsumeAutoHidingEvents(false);
    keyboardPopup.getKeyBoard().setScale(2.5);
    keyboardPopup.getKeyBoard().setLayer(DefaultLayer.DEFAULT);

    keyboardPopup.getKeyBoard().setOnKeyboardCloseButton((e) -> {
        keyboardPopup.hide();
    });

    // listen to width changes and center 
    keyboardPopup.widthProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> {
        keyboardPosX = (screenWidth - nv.doubleValue()) / 2d;
        keyboardPopup.getScene().getWindow().setX(keyboardPosX);
    });
}

public void showKeyboard(Node node) {
    keyboardPosX = (screenWidth - keyboardPopup.getWidth())/2;
    keyboardPosY = screenHeight;
    keyboardPopup.show(node, keyboardPosX, keyboardPosY);
}
```